# How to compare the results of different statistical tests?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, t-test

I don't know if it is a good question or not.

Here's the case, say I have a scale/continuous dependent variable and a bunch of independent variables. My ultimate goal is to build a model to predict/estimate the dependent variable using these independent variables. I believe it's a common setting.

The point is that I know the physical meaning of all the variables, but I don't know their detailed relationship (or even related or not). I want to build a model more from an analysis/explanation point of view so that I could get some real-world insights from the model, instead of a black box.

My approach is trying to use CHAID kind of algorithm to build a decision tree type of model. At every branch, I want to statistically test each independent variable to see if there's relation between it and the dependent variable. Then, based on the test result, I want to pick the most powerful one to build my tree.

The problem is, unlike CHAID algorithm, where most variables are categorical, in my case, the dependent variable is scale, and independent variables are categorical or scale, which means I might need to do different statistical tests for different variables, e.g. t-test and ANOVA for categorical ones and regression for continuous ones. I'm wondering how should I fairly compare these results to pick the most powerful one? (like the correction step in CHAID)

Any idea on any part of my plan is of great importance to me! Thanks!